# Let $x = (11, 2)^T$ . Find both reflection matrices $M$ such that $Mx$ is a multiple of $e_1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How would I go about solving this? I believe my professor said that it deals with householder matrices. I feel like I should calculate $v = x + ||x|| e_1$  and then calculate  $u = \frac{v}{||v||}$ but idk where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of a Householder matrix, but if you understand rotations and reflections, this problem isn't so bad. What follows will almost certainly take longer than using Householder matrices, but is hopefully enlightening.

So, to start, we'll think about rotations. It turns out that the matrix

$$R_\theta = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$

will rotate point through an angle $\theta$. You can derive this if you understand that multiplication by $e^{i\theta}$ rotates complex numbers through an angle $\theta$. Multiply $x + iy$ by $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$; it's the same as $R_\theta(x, y)^T$.

It's not hard to verify that the inverse of $R_\theta$ is $R_{-\theta} = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}.$

Now we need a reflection matrix. Any one one will do, but certain reflections have nice matrix representations (as you'll shortly see, they are atypical). For example, the matrices

$$F_{\text{v}} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix},\ F_{\text{h}} = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},\ F_{(1, 1)} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

represent "flips" across the $x$-axis (vertical flip, hence $F_\text{v}$), $y$-axis, and about the line $y = x$, respectively. I'll choose to use $F_\text{v}$, primarily because it represents a reflection about an axis whose angle is $0$.

OK, now we've got all the background out of the way, and we'd like to find a way to reflect across an arbitrary vector $(a, b)$. Our strategy will be to rotate the plane so that $(a, b)$ lies along the $x$-axis, use $F_{\text{v}}$ to perform our reflection, then rotate the plane back. If we knew the our point $(a, b)$ has angle $\phi$ measured from the $x$-axis, then we'd know that we're looking for the transformation

$$F_{(a, b)} = R_\phi F_\text{v} R_{-\phi} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos^2\phi - \sin^2\phi & 2\cos\phi\sin\phi \\ 2\cos\phi\sin\phi & \sin^2\phi - \cos^2\phi \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(2\phi) & \sin(2\phi) \\ \sin(2\phi) & -\cos(2\phi) \end{pmatrix},$$

because we need to rotate $(a, b)$ through an angle $-\phi$ to wind up back on the $x$-axis. Thankfully, trigonometry tells us everything we need to know, and that angle is $\phi = \arctan (b/a)$.

Now, we can use trig identities to simplify the above, and it'll be a little tedious; we'd have to use some double-angle formulas, and fun stuff like that. But your problem actually simplifies the whole matter, since we'll be interested in half-angles to begin with!

This is because we don't actually want to reflect across the line with angle $\phi = \arctan(b/a)$, but $\phi/2$ (draw a picture to convince yourself that this is true). Not only will a reflection across $\phi/2$ reflect $(a, b)$ to a multiple of $e_1$, but $\frac{\pi - \phi}{2}$ will as well (again, draw a picture).

To see just how nice this situation is, let's let $\alpha = \phi/2$. Then we're after the matrix

$$ R_\alpha = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(2\alpha) & \sin(2\alpha) \\ \sin(2\alpha) & -\cos(2\alpha) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi) \\ \sin(\phi) & -\cos(\phi) \end{pmatrix}.$$

Since our angle $\phi = \arctan(b/a)$, these entries can all be simplified, as $\cos(\arctan(b/a)) = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$, and $\sin(\arctan(b/a)) = \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$.

Thus, tying it all together, your first matrix sending $(a, b) \mapsto ke_1$ via reflection, will be

$$R_\alpha = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}  & \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}  \\ \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}  & \frac{-a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}  \end{pmatrix}.$$ Recall that, for the second, you'll use $\beta = \frac{\pi - \arctan(b/a)}{2}$, where $R_\beta$ should simply interchang sine and cosine in $R_\alpha$ (don't trust me on that, it's just my instinct; there may be some negative signs floating around somewhere, or I could be completely wrong).